# change input value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing an assignment for a uni subject and having some trouble with javascript. I want to be able to change the value of an input field based on the value of another field. in short, the purpose is to input a quantity of a product in one field, and have the field next to it change to display the total amount of money required to purchase that quantity of products.

When I run my html, the quantity entered does not change the value of the cost field and im thinking there must be something wrong with my javascript.

Here is a copy of my javascript function, and the related html for it to execute within.

SCRIPT:

```
function calcRowWash(){ 
    var theForm = document.forms["orderform"];
    var x = theForm.getElementById("quantc").value;
    var quantity = 0;
    if(x.value!=""){
        quantity = parseInt(x.value);
    }
    var totalC = (quantity*0.30);
    document.getElementById("totc").value = totalC;
    return;
}
```

HTML:

```
<td width = "90px" align ="left"><input type = "text" id ="quantc" name = "quantWash" size = "5" tabindex = "13" onblur="calcRowWash()"/></td>
<td width = "90px" align ="left"><input type = "hidden" id ="totc" name = "washtotal" size = "5" tabindex = "14" value=""/></td>
```

Thanks for the help!.

Comment: I'm trying to format your code sensibly (as code) in order to help, and remove the unnecessary helper-prompts (the `\`Enter code here\`` messages). I'm not trying to compete.

Comment: try to debug your code and see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
var theForm = document.forms["orderform"]; 
var x = theForm.getElementById("quantc").value;
```

This is redundant. IDs are unique on the entire document, so this will suffice:

```
var x = document.getElementById('quantc');
```

Also note that I removed the `.value` - this was the problem, because you then tried to get the value... of the value.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain why the answer is not satisfactory?

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
calcRowWash = (function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("quantc");
    var quantity = 0;

    if (x.value!="") quantity = parseInt(x.value);

    var totalC = (quantity*0.30);
    document.getElementById("totc").value = totalC;

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rfsrj/1/).

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
    function calcRowWash() {
        var x = document.forms[0]['quantc'].value;
        var quantity = 0;
        if (x != "") {
            quantity = parseInt(x);
        }
        var totalC = (quantity * 0.30);
        document.forms[0]['totc'].value = totalC.toString();

    }
```

Html Markup, I've changed the hidden type for an textbox and It works for me.

```
   <td width = "90px" align ="left"><input type = "text" id ="quantc" tabindex = "13" onblur="calcRowWash()"/></td>
 <td width = "90px" align ="left"><input type = "text" id ="totc" tabindex = "13"/></td>  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calcRowWash(){ 
    var theForm = document.forms["orderform"];
    var x = theForm.getElementById("quantc").value;
    var quantity = 0;

    // Check if it is not empty
    if(x.value != ""){
        // Check if it is a valid number
        if(x / x == 1){
            quantity = parseInt(x.value);
        }
    }
    var totalC = (quantity * 0.30);
    document.getElementById("totc").value = totalC;
}
```

this works for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form name="myForm" action="#" method="POST">
   <input type = "text" id="quantc" name = "quantWash" size = "5" tabindex = "13"   onblur="calcRowWash()"/>
   <input type = "hidden" id ="totc" name = "washtotal" size = "5" tabindex = "14" value=""/>
</form>

function calcRowWash(){ 
   var quantity = document.myForm.quantWash.value; 
   var price = 10.0;
   document.myForm.washtotal.value = quantity * price;
}
```

The function doesn't comprise the parsing stuff. I just want to show how to read and set the value of both input fields.

Comment: this doesnt work, i understand how to read the input field. but for some reason when running the page containing the script, and entering a value into the input field, the value of the washtotal field does not display anything, and remains blank. why this is so is my question...shouldnt the function be triggered by the onblur event?

Comment: your second input field is hidden <input type = "hidden" id ="totc" name = "washtotal"... Change it to "text". I just tested it and it works for me.

Comment: youre right it does. i had to create a new page with the same table and javascript for it to work though. there must be something wrong with my javascript or html elsewhere

Answer (score -2):

You can use this JavaScript Code:

```
var inp = document.getElementById("inp"); // getting the Input ID
function change_value() {
    inp.value = 'Your Value'; // <-- value 
}
```

You can add Events:

```
inp.onfocus = change_value;
inp.onblur = another function with another action;
```

Good Luck Liam and Have a Nice Day.